# Особенности работы работы со ссылками в for

Tags: java

Весь `for` без проблем проходит, когда выходим из всех циклов, все внутренние `List`-ы в `list` обнуляются. Это особенность работы со ссылками?

```
    List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> bufList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            bufList.add("j: " + j);
        }
        list.add(bufList);
        bufList.clear();
    }

    bufList = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Да, конечно. Вы кладете в `list` ссылки на `bufList`, а потом этот `bufList` очищаете.

Comment: Но внутри цикла очитка проходит корректно, без затираний всех данных

Comment: Вы добавляете один и тот же лист, а потом очищаете его. В итоге у вас будет куча ссылок на один очищенный лист

Comment: Как вы это определили?

Comment: В дебагере внутри цикла bufList добавляется в list, обнуляется, набирает 100 элементов и добавляется снова. Так все 100 раз, когда выходим из for все внутренние списки в list очищаются

Comment: @CosmicFlow, а если посмотреть всё содержимое, а не только последний список?

Comment: У всех элементов ("j: 58" в 61 элементе list, к примеру) есть байтовое value. Внутри for они существуют.  
P.s. Ок, мне уже стыдно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новый объект для списка создается когда вызывается его конструктор. Конструктор для списка объектов в коде вызывается только один раз:

```
List<Object> bufList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Следовательно в Вашем коде используется только один список, на который ссылается переменная `bufList`. Ссылка на него сто раз добавляется во внешний список списков (`list`).  Соответственно, после очистки `bufList` все ссылки ведут на пустой список.

Можете проверить это непосредственно в цикле:

```
list.add(bufList);
bufList.clear();
System.out.println(list.get(i).size()); // 0, т.к. list.get(i) указывает на тот же объект, что и bufList
```

Чтобы этого избежать нужно создавать новые объекты, например, при добавлении в `list`:

```
list.add(new ArrayList<>(bufList));
```